# Dynamically allocate Multi-dimensional array of structure using C++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic

For a school project, I'm trying to dynamically declare an array of structures with the rows and cols as inputs from the command line interface. I've been reading about pointer to pointer concepts and want to know is my definition correct with respect to what I need. 
So basically I need an array of structures which can be expanded dynamically with respect to both rows and cols. 
I've done this so far.

In the global scope

```
struct st2_D
{
uint8_t ucvar1;
uint32_t ui32var2; 
}
st2_D ** ppst2_D;
```

In `main()`, I've the following definition:

```
ppst2_D = new st2_D * [rows]
for(uint32_t var = 0; var < rows; var++) ppst2_D[var] = new st2_d[cols]
```

So will this create an array of structures with the given rows and cols? Also, how will I access the elements of the structure at a particular row and col?

Comment: You know how to use index for a "1d" array-like object (you do it with `ppst2_D[var]`). How do you *think* you would extend the syntax to index a "2d" array-like object?

Answer (score 1):

These statements

```
ppst2_D = new st2_D * [rows]
for(uint32_t var = 0; var < rows; var++) ppst2_D[var] = new st2_d[cols]
```

create a one-dimensional array of pointers to the type st2_D. And then `rows` one-dimensional arrays of the type ppst2_D[var] are created.

You can use either indices as with usual two-dimensional arrays as for example

```
ppst2_D[i][j]
```

Or you can use for example the pointer arithmetic as for example

```
*( *( ppst2_D + i ) + j )
```

or even their combinations as for example

```
( *( ppst2_D + i ) )[j]
```

or

```
*( ppst2_D[i] + j )
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 5;
    int **a = new int *[n];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = new int[n];
    }

    for ( int **p = a; p != a + n; ++p )
    {
        for ( int *q = *p; q != *p + n; ++q )
        {
            *q = q - *p + ( p - a ) * n;
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << a[i][j] << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        delete [] *( a + i );
    }

    delete [] a;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
 0  1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24
```

Comment: So this methodology will work for multidimensional structures also right? Because you've taken an example for integer.

Comment: @NISHITKHARA  The type of elements of the array is not important.